# PostgreSQL: raise error if planner needs to do an sequence scan

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning

I want to check if our code does use only indexed columns.

I think it does, but I want to be sure.

How can I configure/modify PostgreSQL to raise an exception if it **needs** to do an sequence scan?

It is ok, if PostgreSQL **wants** to do an sequence scan, but an index exists.

Then I run our software tests to see if an exception gets raised.

Comment: You could run `explain` on your statements first and check the output.

Comment: In addition, you can't stop PostgreSQL from using sequential scans, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-ENABLE-SEQSCAN

Comment: @Colin'tHart yes I could run "explain" on every query I execute. But sometimes a sequence scan is done even if an index exists. That's ok, and I don't want to raise in exception in this case. Any way to detect these sequence scans?

Comment: I am not sure if this does not give you more work than necessary.  When you carpet bomb the DB with indexes based on assumptions about their necessity, you realize later that many of these are unused.  (There are obvious cases where an index _will_ be needed, but those are usually known already at physical data modelling time.)

Comment: And don't forget that a sequential scan of the table can be faster than an index scan and associated table lookup. I'm missing the "why" aspect to your question.

Comment: I agree with Colin. It is a common misconception that a seq scan is a (always) bad thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I know that in my db schema tables have either less then 100 or more than 10M rows, then I think there should be no sequence scan, except the table is one of the "less than 100 rows" tables. When is a seq scan a good plan if the table has more than 10M rows?

Comment: @guettli `SELECT count(1) FROM thing WHERE t_created >= now() - interval '1 year';`

Comment: "*When is a seq scan a good plan if the table has more than 10M rows*" - `select customer_id, avg(order_amount) from orders group by customer_id` for starters or any query that needs more than **approximately** 15% of the rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Where does the seq happen in your example? I still think my idea is not bad. Before the `raise` I will check an exclude list of statements which are OK.